# Eclipse CDT generate method definition to header file

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

Using `Ctrl + 1` in Eclipse CDT only suggests `Rename in file` and `Rename in workspace`.

How can I automatically add non existing method definition to .hpp of a class?

Foo.hpp

```
class Foo{
};
```

From the code below do something like `Ctrl + 1` then `Generate method definition`.

```
#include <Foo.hpp>

Foo foo;
foo.doSome();
```

Will lead to this

```
class Foo{
 public:
  void doSome();
};
```

After accomplishing the steps above then I can now use `Source` then `implement method`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a "Create function" or "Create method" quick fix. There isn't one currently, but [bug 335442](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=335442) is on file for adding one.